# How do I generate a sequence of numbers like this?

Tags: bash, seq

I am trying to generate a sequence of numbers where it adds 1 every other time, and 39999 every other time. Example of list which does what I want up to a million:

```
1 40000
40001 80000
80001 120000
120001 160000
160001 200000
200001 240000
240001 280000
280001 320000
320001 360000
360000 400000
400001 440000
440001 480000
480001 520000
520001 560000
560001 600000
600001 640000
640001 680000
680001 720000
720001 760000
760001 800000
800001 840000
840001 880000
880001 920000
920001 960000
960001 1000000
```

I have tried using `seq`, but I did not find a way to change the increment every other time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output the sequence "manually" using

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 1000000 ]; do
    printf '%d %d\n' "$(( i+1 ))" "$(( i += 40000 ))"
done
```

or

```
for (( i = 1; i < 1000000; i += 40000 )); do
    printf '%d %d\n' "$i" "$(( i + 39999 ))"
done
```

or something like it.

Or `paste` together two separate sequences from `seq`:

```
$ paste <( seq 1 40000 1000000 ) <( seq 40000 40000 1000000 )
1       40000
40001   80000
80001   120000
120001  160000
160001  200000
200001  240000
240001  280000
280001  320000
320001  360000
360001  400000
400001  440000
440001  480000
480001  520000
520001  560000
560001  600000
600001  640000
640001  680000
680001  720000
720001  760000
760001  800000
800001  840000
840001  880000
880001  920000
920001  960000
960001  1000000
```

Suggested by JdeBP [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494309/how-do-i-generate-a-sequence-of-numbers-like-this/494310?noredirect=1#comment908317_494310):

```
jot - 1 1000000 40000 | awk '{ print $1, $1+39999 }'
```

but it's essentially the same as the second loop at the top, and since `seq` is more readily available on Linux machines (`jot` is originally a BSD utility, while `seq` is part of GNU coreutils), and the most common visitor here is a Linux user, and the question was tagged with [seq](/questions/tagged/seq), it may be more usefully written as

```
seq 1 40000 1000000 | awk '{ print $1, $1+39999 }'
```

Comment: Don't forget the option of piping `jot` into `awk`.  (-:

Comment: Yeah, and you should also put a `cat` (or two `tac(1)`s) between `jot` and `awk`.

Comment: @mosvy A cat in a pipeline is (often) a sad cat.

Answer (score 4):

Enjoy a single `AWK` expression :)

```
awk 'BEGIN{ while (c < 1000000) print (++c, c += 39999) }'
```

- `++c` - *pre* increment variable

The output:

```
1 40000
40001 80000
80001 120000
120001 160000
160001 200000
200001 240000
240001 280000
280001 320000
320001 360000
360001 400000
400001 440000
440001 480000
480001 520000
520001 560000
560001 600000
600001 640000
640001 680000
680001 720000
720001 760000
760001 800000
800001 840000
840001 880000
880001 920000
920001 960000
960001 1000000
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be greatly simplified,

```
for i in $(seq 0 24); do
  printf "$(($i * 40000 + 1)) $((($i+1) * 40000))\n";
done;

1 40000
40001 80000
80001 120000
120001 160000
160001 200000
200001 240000
240001 280000
280001 320000
320001 360000
360001 400000
400001 440000
440001 480000
480001 520000
520001 560000
560001 600000
600001 640000
640001 680000
680001 720000
720001 760000
760001 800000
800001 840000
840001 880000
880001 920000
920001 960000
960001 1000000
```